IP address allocation by RIRs to countries and asns
I am trying to build a geoip blocking service. I have data on ips allocated by RIRs to countries. I am now looking for ips allocated to autonomous systems by the RIRs. Where can I find such data, ideally this will be a file in any format and not data presented on a front end website. I need to hit this link programatically and update these rules at some regular frequency.
Id also like to know if possible which of the autonomous systems that have been assigned ips by the RIR are in fact ISPs. An organization large enough to request an asn directly from an RIR is unlikely to be the source of malicious traffic but the same cant be said for the end users of any isp.
Im thinking, in addition to the country blacklist, i can also permanently whitelist all ips allocated to asns at the RIR level.

I don't know that this is on topic as its asking for a service recommendation - but putting that aside your assumptions seem very shaky "an organisation large enough to request an ASN directly from am RIR is unlikely to be the source of malicious traffic" - nothing prevents users of IPS provided by these providers being compromised (look no further then Azure, Google Cloud and AWS).

Do RIR's even allocate IP's to AS's? Is it not more that an accpunt at an RIR can include AS's and IP's?

Most such asns will not be cloud providers but apple, ford, dod etc etc. Prop of all traffic from such end users that are directly allocated ips and thats malicious should be zero. But you are correct. So, even better if I can filter out both isps and cloud providers, anyone that is not an enduser but has been allocated an asn and ip ranges, and blacklist them.

RIRs allocate ips to ASNs, NIRs, ISPs, LIRs etc. Autonomous systems that are isps or cloud providers further sub allocate down the chain. These allocations are publicly available.

You can download the free IP address ranges by ASN database from https://lite.ip2location.com/database-asn
The free list is being updated in monthly basis.

Whats the source for the ip-asn data? This may be what Im looking for, though I remember reading there are about 70,000 asn's but the ipv4 db has about 6 lakh rows, 3.5 lakh non blank asn names, and just 10,000 unique asn names, so not the entire list maybe?
